# Mock a method to get code coverage in Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking, opengl-es-2.0

I am writing an Android OpenGL ES 2.0 application in a test driven fashion. Here goes my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         boolean checkCompatability = checkForDeviceCompatablity();


         if(checkCompatability)
         {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Your device is opengl compatible", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
         else
         {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your device does not support OpenGL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
    }

    public boolean checkForDeviceCompatablity() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        ConfigurationInfo info = manager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
        boolean result = info.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000
            || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                    >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1);

        return result;
    }

}
```

And this is my test

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public MainActivityTest(Class<MainActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    public MainActivityTest(){
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    //The below method would always return me a true as I test it in a real device.
    public void testIntegrationCheckForConfiguration() {
        mActivity = getActivity();
        mActivity.startActivity(mActivity.getIntent());
        boolean resultConfiguration = mActivity.checkForDeviceCompatablity();
        assertNotNull(resultConfiguration);
    }

    //I need to mock the above method into something like the below method so that I can get coverage for the else block.
    public void testCheckForConfigurationWhenDeviceIsOfInCorrectConfiguration(){
        mActivity = new MainActivity(){
            @Override
            public boolean checkForDeviceCompatablity() {
                return false;
            }
        };
        mActivity.startActivity(mActivity.getIntent());
        boolean compatability = mActivity.checkForDeviceCompatablity();
        assertTrue(compatability);
    }
}
```

I know I'm doing it incorrectly. But I need a way to mock the `checkForDeviceCompatability` to  make it return false. When I run the test I get a NullPointerException at the `startActivity` call. How do I mock the function checkForDeviceCompatability and get the code cover the else part in MainActivity class?

Also is this possible with any kind of mocking framework?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I have much experience with this sort of thing but you could try [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

Noticed it in the examples when integrating [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) dependency injection to my app.

Comment: Yeah I thought of considering that as an option too, but then I would be doing the same by creating the object and initiating the startActivity which would again lead me to a NullPointerException.